# Residues of the Gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function, residue-calculus

I am trying to make sense of a proof that the poles of $\Gamma(z)$ are at $z=-n$ and have residue $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. The proof reduces $\Gamma(z)$ to the sum of an (entire) incomplete gamma function and a meromorphic part given by $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!(z+n)}$$
My issue is the expansion $$\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{1+z}+\frac{1}{2(z+2)}- ...$$
does not resemble a Laurent Series since each term is centered around a different point. Can someone explain why it is still valid to take the coefficient of $(z-z_0)^{-1}$ in this form in order to find the residue at $z=z_0$?

Comment: Where did you find this proof?

Comment: Complex Analysis lecture slides

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Residues

Comment: Oh yes I see now that you can simply recombine the terms without worrying about a Laurent series, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!